# JIRA linked issues and their total effort/worked on time

Tags: jira, estimation

I need to start using JIRA for estimation and came across a scenario I have not found a good solution for yet.  Consider an installation with more than one project which is already populated with many existing issues.  Many of these issues are linked to other issues (not necessarily in the same project).

How can we configure a special link (say "parent of") and fields to record both effort estimate and logged work so that when any of the "children" are updated, some special field in the parent gets updated to reflect the corresponding aggregated values?

Just to be clear here, two issues A and B may be linked in more than one way (e.g. "parent of", "duplicate of", "relates to", "depends on", etc).  However, aggregation of the special fields should only happen for a specific type of link.  You can see the point when you think of the "duplicate of" link which clearly should not be aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

Task & Sub-Task has exact same behaviour. Logging work in Sub-Task updates Task's work log counter.